# Regex to match all numbers, letters and punctuation symbols?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want a regex which can match all numbers, letters, and all punctuation symbols as well (full stop, comma, question mark, exclamation mark, colon, etc.).

The string must be at least one character long, but can be any length above that.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are we talking Unicode or ASCII?

Comment: Do you mean that the regex should match all strings that consist of those symbols? Should it match strings that consist of one character, or strings that consist of any number of characters?

Comment: For example, should the regex match the string `5`, and should it match the string `(Here is an example. 12345 !?,.;)` as well?

Comment: @m.buettner Not sure, but htaccess.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Yes, any number of characters.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to think what is should NOT match...

Comment: @AndersonGreen Any combination of any characters, letters and punctuation symbols are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\\p{Graph}+` or `\\p{Print}+`

```
@Test
public void shouldMatch()
{
    assertTrue("asdf123ASFD!@#$%^&*()".matches("\\p{Graph}+"));
}

@Test
public void shouldMatchWithWhitespaces()
{
    assertTrue("asdf 123 ASFD !@#$%^&*()".matches("[\\p{Graph}\\s]+"));
}
```

You can get more infos here (Section: POSIX character classes (US-ASCII only)):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, it should be easy. Please try:

```
([^\s]+)
```

This regex match one or more occurrences of any characters but not a space.
This is the easiest way to match (and reuse) any string. Maybe you already know what's parenthesis means in regular expressions. They are used for backreference, I.e. to reuse later the matched string.

Comment: It is not 100% clear from the question what he/she wants to match. But I would guess it is not every character.

Comment: "Letters, numbers and any punctuation character"... :) maybe you're right, but IMHO, considering also that in the post tag there's "htaccess", he is very likely trying a rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Start by looking at character classes

http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

An example:

```
[A-Za-z_0-9]*
```

Will match anything with standard letters in ascii plus the underscore.

You can add your desired punctuation to the set.

You can use \w to match any word characters, and depending on which regex implementation you use it may match unicode characters too.

Another approach is to decide what you DON'T want to match. If you want to match a string of characters that are not whitespace you could use

```
\S*
```